# Codename One - using L10NManager instead of DateFormat (deprecated) to get current Locale date-time format

Tags: java, locale, codenameone, date-format

My CodenameOne app (iOS port of an Android app) shows a date-time format example to the user, according to the Locale.

This is the Java code in my Android app:

```
static String getTheCurrentLocaleDateTimeFormatString() {
    return ((SimpleDateFormat) DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance()).toLocalizedPattern();
}
```

For example in my Locale I get this string:

```
dd MMM y HH:mm:ss
```

No modification to the app design can be done on this.

Documentation here : https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/java/text/DateFormat.html

says DateFormat is deprecated and has issue on some platforms, like iOS itself. It is only used for this, I left it in my Android app by the way.

However, I can't use its methods because they are not the same in CodenameOne, if I am not wrong.

Documentation says to use  L10NManager instead, but I have to change the code.

What is the right way to use L10NManager to achieve the same goal?

Answer (score 0):

You can use L10NManager like this:

```
String t = L10NManager.getInstance().formatDateTime(date);
```

We support `SimpleDateFormat` too but it's a bit more limited. We have a version of it in `com.codename1.l10n` which works more consistently across platforms.

Comment: Sorry but my question is about the format string. The provided code example in the question works in Android and it yields a string like "dd MMM y HH:mm:ss". The user sees that string, while your code snippet yields a date like "14 ago 2020, 10:42:26"

Comment: There are several other options for formatting in the L10N class for short/long formats. These are determined by the OS so by definition they will be inconsistent. If you want a consistent format you can use SimpleDateFormat directly and include a pattern for the date/time.

Comment: I need just the format string (with letters) of the current Locale date-time. It's used in SimpleDateFormat for sure, to yield the date as in your provided date-time example, so a method could be added, like getCurrentLocaleDatetimeFormatString(). Is it possible to add that method? Otherwise is there a way to get the format string (I need it for the iOS port, not Android)?

Comment: We don't have the format string for iOS since it doesn't exist there. The L10NManager skips the date format stage and does the formatting for you.

Comment: So I guess the L10NManager knows all Locales and does some string procesing. I see that my Locale is respected, because  "14 ago 2020, 10:42:26" is one of the suitable formats. Is it not possible at all to have the format string, based on the internal information that L10NManager is using well. I think that the correspondence with letters (or special groups of letters) is international standard (see Android or Apple documentation)

Comment: No it doesn't know anything. It just invokes the OS native methods to format a date, time, number etc. So it will act completely natively on each OS it's running on. JavaSE did know everything about everything which made it huge. Android also did that but it's an operating system so that's part of its features. Since we package the JVM it doesn't make sense to include all of that overhead.

Comment: I did not study Codename in deep yet. I would like to know if it is possible to call a native function on iOS from the cross-platform project and how to do it. Maybe iOS provides that function for date-time format strings, I have to check it out.

Comment: Yes you can do that pretty easily. See https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html